# Does user space program(runc) regulate the size of physical address space of a docker container process?

Tags: go, operating-system, docker-container, systems-programming, containerd

Below is the CloudFormation template to configure ECS task containers on AWS EC2 instance(Linux):

```
  TodobackendTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:

        - Name: todobackend
          Image: someacct/todobackend
          Memory: 450
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: /var/www/todobackend
              SourceVolume: webroot


        - Name: nginx
          Image: someacct/todobackend-nginx
          Memory: 300
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: "8000"
              HostPort: "8000"
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: /var/www/todobackend
              SourceVolume: webroot

      Volumes:
        - Name: webroot
          Host:
            SourcePath: /ecs/webroot


  TodobackendAdhocTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: todobackend
          Image: someacct/todobackend
          Memory: 245
          MountPoints:
            - ContainerPath: /var/www/todobackend
              SourcePath: webroot

      Volumes:
        - Name: webroot
          Host:
            SourcePath: /ecs/webroot
```

---

where memory attribute for three containers are evenly divided(450+300+250 MB) assuming that these 3 containers are running on `t2.micro` EC2 instance type that has 1 GB RAM allocated(physical)

Changing these values(of `"Memory"`) randomly makes the container  **run or fail** without knowing proper reason for failure.

On failure, we get such errors, on debugging in AWS cloud:

### [image]

**Containers do not run ON docker. Containers are processes - they run on linux kernel. Containers are Linux processes(or Windows)**

Docker container namespace is internally created using `runtime·clone()` system call.

### [image]

Memory management map each process virtual address space to physical address space. Process management refers virtual addresses, but not physical address.

For `Memory: 300`MB syntax in the above code, AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-memory) says: "The amount (in MiB) of memory to present to the container."

---

---

In docker world, `containerd` creates shim process for every new container.
`runc` actually creates a container process.

1)
What does assigning of RAM `Memory: 300`MB size to a container process,  mean?in the above code... Is it a size of physical address space of a process(or virtual address space of a process)?

2)
Does `runc` userspace program use `runtime·clone()` system call to set physical memory space(`Memory: 300`MB) for each container process?

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1650f1ba0b964a06a242c3318e85b3b46f010614/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s#L540

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `memory` parameter in such a small instance with such minimum memory, remember there is one big difference between these two, by reaching memory limit your container will be **killed**.

With memoryReservation you container can consume more memory and if one container under load then it will able consume memory more then desired limit.

**memoryReservation**

> The soft limit (in MiB) of memory to reserve for the container. When
>   system memory is under contention, Docker attempts to keep the
>   container memory to this soft limit; h**owever, your container can
>   consume more memory when needed**.

**memory**

> The amount (in MiB) of memory to present to the container. **If your
>   container attempts to exceed the memory specified here, the container
>   is killed.**

[container_definition_memory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_memory)

Where this memory parameter not controlled by the container itself but controlled by ECS agent.

[ECS_agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_agent.html)

> How to calculate memory size needed for each docker container?

Where your this question is a concern, this totally depends on the underlying application that you are going to run in the container. I saw you are using nginx you can read here [nginx-plus-sizing-guide](https://www.nginx.com/resources/datasheets/nginx-plus-sizing-guide/)

Comment: I read the documentation on memory. But I don't understand the meaning: The amount (in MiB) of memory to present to the container.? It is OS's memory management decides that aspect

Comment: Yes but it's hard limit if container reaches to this limit it will be killed, so better to use soft limit

Comment: Am not sure.. how userspace programs have control on hard & soft limit? you are trying to tweak "memory management" functionality. Please read my updated query. OS allows you to access only virtual address space in memory...